# Storing additional information in django using absrtactuser

Tags: django, serialization, django-custom-user

I have created custom Userclass in django(AbstarctUser). Everything works fine but my password is getting stored as plain text in database even after registering in admin.py. I do not have any forms.py explicitly defined.

Also I am using nested serializers following [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/nested-relationships-in-serializers-for-onetoone-fields-in-django-rest-framework-bdb4720d81e6).

My code is as below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import BasicUserInfo
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class BasicUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(BasicUserInfo, BasicUserAdmin)
```

### Edited to add Models and views

#### Models.py

```
class BasicUserInfo(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_index=True)

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(BasicUserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### Views.py

```
serializer = AddUserSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
    serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
```

#### Serializers.py

```
class BasicUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BasicUserInfo
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')

    print("hete")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        retval =  BasicUserInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        self.password = make_password(password)
       # self._password = password
        return retval

class AddUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = BasicUserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('phoneNo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = BasicUserSerializer.create(BasicUserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        user_info, created = UserInfo.objects.update_or_create(user=user, phoneNo=validated_data.pop('phoneNo'))
        return user_info
```

Comment: Show your models and views. Django admin just displays info passed through them.

Comment: What does `AddUserSerializer` look like?

Comment: user = BasicUserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('phoneNo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = BasicUserSerializer.create(BasicUserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        user_info, created = UserInfo.objects.update_or_create(user=user, phoneNo=validated_data.pop('phoneNo'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `user.set_password(password)` -> this internally triggers the password hashing mechanism: Here's the Django code that does this:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
    self._password = raw_password

def make_password(password, salt=None, hasher='default'):
    """
    Turn a plain-text password into a hash for database storage

    Same as encode() but generate a new random salt. If password is None then
    return a concatenation of UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX and a random string,
    which disallows logins. Additional random string reduces chances of gaining
    access to staff or superuser accounts. See ticket #20079 for more info.
    """
    if password is None:
        return UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX + get_random_string(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_SUFFIX_LENGTH)
    hasher = get_hasher(hasher)
    salt = salt or hasher.salt()
    return hasher.encode(password, salt)
```

So the problem is `serializers.create(**validated_data)` is not performing the `make_password` operation. The above answer works perfectly fine, except it does two things differently
- It saves the user twice (once in `serailizer.create` and again during `user.save())
- It does not hande everything within the serializer, part of the work is being split b/w the serializer and the view.

If you want to keep it all within the serializer, you can do the following:

```
class AddUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BasicUserInfo

    def validate_password(self, value):
        return make_password(value)
```

### Update:

I've made a bunch of edits; and tried to explain why. Please read patiently, and incorporate changes as you see fit.

```
class BasicUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BasicUserInfo
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')

    def validate_password(self, value):
        return make_password(value)

class AddUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    user = BasicUserSerializer(required=True) 
    class Meta: 
        model = UserInfo 
        fields = ('phoneNo') 

    def create(self, validated_data): 
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user') 
        user_serializer = BasicUserSerializer(data=user_data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = user_serializer.save()
        validated_data['user'] = user
        return UserInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: This returns Hashed password. But my database still contains rawpassword in it

Comment: Please share your full serializer declaration; view file, etc. Partial snapshots are not useful and lead to incomplete understanding of the issue.

Comment: class BasicUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BasicUserInfo
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')

    print("hete")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        retval =  BasicUserInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        self.password = make_password(password)
       # self._password = password
        return retval

Comment: class AddUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = BasicUserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('phoneNo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = BasicUserSerializer.create(BasicUserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        user_info, created = UserInfo.objects.update_or_create(user=user, phoneNo=validated_data.pop('phoneNo'))
        return user_info

Comment: This throws me a runtime error.
"save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". Also are we overriding save function here?

Comment: No it still does not. When I try to post the AddUserSerializer does not get updated. I get error for user NOT NULL constraint failed. Trying to figure out

Comment: What's the json you are posting

Comment: {
 "user":{
  "username":"person124",
  "email":"person124@xyz.com",
  "password":"abc"
 },
 "phoneNo": "9538521221"
}

Comment: Got it, updating code. Error is that the newly created user's ID needs to be set for the add user serialize to save

Comment: Also there is assertion error : AssertionError at /userinfo/
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `userinfo.serializers.AddUserSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

Comment: Ran into another problem. Cannot assign "'person124@xyz.com'": "UserInfo.user" must be a "BasicUserInfo" instance.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot.. It worked. Had to minor change. Used validated_data['user_id'] = user.pk instead of validated_data['user'] = user.pk

Answer (score 0):

You should not use like this:

```
serializer = AddUserSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
    serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
```

if password in validated data

it is better to use like this:

```
password = request.data.pop('password', '')
if not password:
    raise ValidationError('password must not be empty')
serializer = AddUserSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
user = serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

Comment: I am getting Validation error when trying to pop. My JSON format is like below:{
 "user":{
  "username":"randomguy",
  "email":"randomguy@gmail.com",
  "password":"djangoproject"
 },
 "phoneNo": "1234"}

Comment: you should set your password = serializers.CharField(requered=False), and handle this field by yourself (the code above)